# Why is the Indesign Scripts panel suddenly not sorted alphabetically?

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

The Scripts panel in Indesign is sorted alphabetically by filename. Suddenly, the scripts seem to be ordered randomly in the panel.

This gets quite unefficient when trying to quickly find correct scripts in a process where many are used at different parts of a layout process.

Any ideas on how to sort them back alphabetically? Dragging scripts is not possible and there is no "sort" function in the panel menu.

This is how the sample scripts folder looks:

[image]
Edit: This issue got solved with the latest update of Indesign CC, now the items are ordered alphabetically again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is (was?) a well known bug. I was going to post the link to the Adobe bug report and then realized than Adobe staff just replied today than it has been fixed.

https://indesign.uservoice.com/forums/601180-adobe-indesign-bugs/suggestions/31660828-scripts-panel-sorting

Try updating Indesign and see if it works for you.